# something strange with posix threads in C++

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads

I face a strange error with pthreads in C++, I try to run this code:

```
typedef struct
{
    struct sockaddr_in clienAddr;
    int clientLength;
    string message;
}param;

pthread_t clientThread;

param sentParam ;
sentParam.clienAddr = clientAddress;
sentParam.clientLength= client_info;
sentParam.message=buffString;

cout <<"sentParam: "<<sentParam.message<<endl;
// it prints well.

int i = pthread_create(&clientThread, NULL, handleClientRequestRead,&sentParam );
cout <<"i: "<<i<<endl;
the function which be called

void* handleClientRequestRead(void* params)
{
    // cout<<"params: "<< ;
    string msg = (( param *)(params))->message;
}
```

When I try to print msg it's empty. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You must make sure that `sentParam` lives as long as the thread (this usually means then end of the program).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Matteo above:

```
struct param
{
    struct sockaddr_in clienAddr;
    int clientLength;
    string message;
};


 void someFunction()
 {
    static int   sentCount = 0;
    static param sentParam[10];
//  ^^^^^^ Notice these are static
//         Thus they will last the length of the program.
//         An alternative is to dynamically creation but then you have
//         to destroy them at some point.
//


    if (count >= 10)
    {    throw std::runtime_error("Too many threads");
    }
//         If you want to keep more than 10 or use a dynamic number 
//         then use a std::list, NOT a std::vector

    sentParam[sentCount].clienAddr = clientAddress;
    sentParam[sentCount].clientLength= client_info;
    sentParam[sentCount].message=buffString;

    cout <<"sentParam: "<<sentParam.message<<endl;
    // it prints well.


    pthread_t clientThread;
    int i = pthread_create(&clientThread, NULL, handleClientRequestRead,&sentParam[sentCount] );
    cout <<"i: "<<i<<endl;

    if (i == 0)
    {
        ++sentCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Lokai Astrai but If I defined the struct as static, isn't this means that every time the function invoked the same values are taken?

Comment: @AdamJohns: No. static means it is initialized the first time the function is called (and only the first time). But it lives to the end of the application. When you return and re-enter the function the values in a static variables have the same value as when you left (think of them as global variables (in terms of lifespan) but you can only see them inside the function).

Comment: AdamJohns: Please Accept @Matteo Italia he has the real answer I was just expanding on what he said and future readers of the question should see his answer first as it will help them more mine just adds more information.

Answer (score 6):

My guess is that when `handleClientRequestRead` gets called `sentParam` has already gone out of scope and its memory has been reused for other purposes.

You should allocate memory for your parameters in a location that will still be valid when you'll access it from the thread (e.g. on the heap, keeping in mind that you must free it when you don't need it anymore; a valid help can be `shared_ptr`).

By the way, in C++ you don't need the `typedef` trick for `struct`s.

Comment: I got you, But my program doesn't stop after invoking the thread, how can I guarantee that my object still on the heap

Comment: @AdamJohns: if you allocate memory with `new` it stays there until you explicitly call `delete`.

Comment: @AdamJohns: Or you can make it static storage duration (i.e. global).